# Splitting strings delimited by [[ ]] in java?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have the input string of the following form `"[[Animal rights]] [[Anthropocentrism]] [[Anthropology]]"` and I need to extract the tokens `"Animal rights" , "Anthropocentrism"` and so on etc.

I tried using the split method in the String library but I am not able to find the appropriate regular expression to get the tokens, it would be great if someone could help.

I am basically trying to parse the internal links in a Wikipedia XML file you can check out the format [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help%3aWiki_markup#Links_and_URLs).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably shouldn't be using `split()` here but instead a [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html):

```
String input = "[[Animal rights]] [[Anthropocentrism]] [[Anthropology]]";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\[\\[(.*?)\\]\\]").matcher(input);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

```
Animal rights
Anthropocentrism
Anthropology
```

Comment: can you point me to some good tutorial where I can practice some regex questions, I do want to learn this stuff

Comment: Can you tell how shall I iterate on this group you found out using matcher, I actually want to store all these strings in an array for further processing.

Comment: thanks a lot, I just modified my code with ArrayLists and it worked :)

Comment: @arshajii : just accepted your answer but don't know who downvoted the question was it that bad a question.

Comment: @Coder People usually want to see what you've tried as opposed to *just* the question. I'm assuming that's what the downvote was for.

Answer (score 2):

A pattern like this should work:

```
\[\[(.*?)\]\]
```

This will match a literal `[[` followed by zero or more of any character, non-greedily, captured in group 1, followed by a literal `]]`.

Don't forget to escape the `\` in the Java string literal:

```
Pattern.compile("\\[\\[(.*)?\\]\\]");
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy with regex.

```
\[\[(.+?)\]\]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/OPjITeOknq2aeay7)

I recommend doing a `.+` to make sure there is something actually in the brackets and **you won't get a `null`** if something doesn't exist when you're trying to put it in your array.

```
string output = new string [10]; 
string pattern =  "\[\[(.+?)\]\]";
string input = "[[Animal rights]] [[Anthropocentrism]] [[Anthropology]]";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(input);

int increment= 0;
while (m.find()) {
    output[increment] = m.group(1);
    increment++;
}
```

Since you said you wanted to learn regex also i'll break it down.

- `\[` *2x* is finding `[` brackets you need a `\` because it's regex's special characters
- `.` can denote every character except newlines
- `+` means one or more of that character
- `?` Repeats the previous item once or more. Lazy, so the engine first matches the previous item only once, before trying permutations with ever increasing matches of the preceding item.
- `\]` is capturing the `]`

Comment: can you point me to some good tutorial where I can practice some regex questions, I do want to learn this stuff

Comment: @Coder http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a great site for general information about regular expressions and also has plenty of info on the various different regex engines out there.

Comment: @Coder I recommend this [web site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) along with [debugexx](http://www.debuggex.com/) to test how your regex is coming out also they have a very useful "cheat sheet" at the bottom. I literally learned regex 2 weeks ago and i feel like a pro.

Answer (score 0):

Try the next:

```
String str = "[[Animal rights]] [[Anthropocentrism]] [[Anthropology]]";
str = str.replaceAll("(^\\[\\[|\\]\\]$)", "");
String[] array = str.split("\\]\\] \\[\\[");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
// prints "[Animal rights, Anthropocentrism, Anthropology]"
```